# SSHD Consuming 100% of CPU (Hundreds of processes) - Will not die

Tags: linux, openssh

Recently I've noticed that SSHd on a few systems I administrate will start spawning unstoppable processes which will consume huge amounts of CPU.

The syscall shows that the processes are all 'running' and are not zombie or waiting for their parent to kill them (at least not as far as I can tell).

[image]

I've tried everything to kill these processes... the only reliable method I've found to date is to restart the whole server (which isn't ideal). I've tried switching out openssh-server for dropbear, but it doesn't behave the way I need it to for my applications.

I've tried:

```
killall -9 sshd
```

killing each sshd by it's id.
Few other misc things (htop + sigterm, etc...)

I'd love some ideas either for killing these processes or for solving what causes this.

Comment: Seems you are under attack, somebody playing with your security implementation. Are those sshd the latest patched versions?

Comment: Try moving them from the default port 22/TCP to some arbitrary high port to get rid of most automated script scanners. This is NOT a security measure, it just keeps your logs sane. Just for good measure triple check your security and think about deploying fail2ban.

Comment: And, while you are at it, chkrootkit and rkhunter too. You never know...

Comment: While it is on port 22, it does have fail2ban with low limits and high  ban times. I've looked at netstat, etc... very few SSH connections that aren't expected.

Comment: Update: Server is set to key only, fail2ban is enabled, not a lot of inbound connections.

Comment: Can it be that these processes are not really sshd, but rather different binaries with the same name? This might happen if someone has gained access to your system...

Comment: I did an MD5 and the binary matched up. I switched from open ssh to dropbear and the problem stopped occurring. I'm thinking I had a bad version of ssh and it didn't like some of the large file transfers that happen occasionally to the system via rsync with ssh. I have no way of definitively showing that with proof at the moment so I didn't mark this as resolved in case anyone else comes up with a better reason.

Comment: About chkrootkit  I would Highly discourage it  as Its known to give false positives   rkhunter however is what I regularly use..

Comment: You should try `strace` the process to see what syscalls it is calling. But every non-zombie process which is not in non-interruptible sleep (like waiting for dead disk) should be killable by `kill -9`.

Answer (score 3):

If those are actually OpenSSH sshd's, my guess would be that a script somewhere is running them in a broken loop and one of their child processes are hogging up all that CPU.

As Marki555 suggested, `strace` would help you, but you should use `strace -f` so that strace will follow the child processes. From `man strace`:

```
   -f          Trace child processes as they are  created  by  cur-
               rently  traced  processes as a result of the fork(2)
               system call.
```

Because strace generates so much data, it might also be a good idea to use the -e argument as well (for example, to only show open() calls):

```
   -e expr     A qualifying expression which modifies which  events
               to  trace  or  how to trace them.  The format of the
               expression is:
                         [qualifier=][!]value1[,value2]...
```

Another command you can try is `ps xaf` or `pstree -a` to get an easy to understand tree view of processes and their children processes so that you can determine what process started those sshd's. `lsof` might also help you, it'll tell you what files a process has open.

And of course, make sure you're using the latest OpenSSH. I'm thinking rsync + big files + ssh on an ancient OpenSSH 3.4p1 would be problematic.

If those are NOT really sshd processes, then an MD5 checksum of the binary file might display correctly but it might not be the actual sshd program running. Also the `md5sum` command itself could be a backdoored version that's modified to report the correct checksum for certain files (like sshd).

You should take a look at /proc/[sshd pid]/exe and make sure it's a symlink to /usr/sbin/sshd (or wherever your sshd is), as well as /proc/[sshd pid]/environ to see what environment variables it's using, and /proc/[sshd pid]/cmdline to see what command actually started it.

Though an attacker could have renamed the malicious program to "sshd" then executed it to make it appear to be sshd. Could have even moved /usr/sbin/sshd to /tmp/sshd then moved the malicious sshd to /usr/sbin/sshd to attempt to hide it from that type of /proc analysis, but when /tmp/sshd gets moved back to /usr/sbin/sshd the /proc/[sshd pid]/exe symlink will show in `ls` as:

```
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 19 06:47 /proc/[sshd pid]/exe ->  (deleted)/usr/sbin/sshd
```

Also, if those sshd's are doing something to actively prevent normal process analysis, you could try `kill -STOP` instead of `kill -9` to "pause" the process (use `kill -CONT` to resume it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29#Implementation).

However, if an attacker has root privileges then a rootkit could be installed that's hiding from /proc, netstat, ls, etc. If you're really compromised, best course of action is to take the system offline and mount it's partitions on another (clean) system then do the forensics (or use one of those live Linux CDs made for forensics).